# How to describe this function definition?

Tags: haskell

Is this the correct way to describe a function specification and definition

MagicHaskeller generates a function given a specification.

For example the specification : `f [ 3 , 4 , 5.6 ] ~= 4.2` 
generates the function `f = (\a b -> sum a / 3)`

Put another way : the function : `f [ 3 , 4 , 5.6 ] ~= 4.2` accepts a list of three values and generates an approximate value by applying a transformation to these list values. The function generated `f = (\a b -> sum a / 3)` takes a function a which sums the list values and divides by 3. I think the statement `takes a function a which sums the list values and divides by 3` is incorrect. What is the correct interpretation of the function `f = (\a b -> sum a / 3)` ?

Is my terminology correct ?

Comment: Uhm.. something looks wrong to me: the function `f = (\a b -> sum a / 3)` does _not_ satisfy the specification `f [ 3 , 4 , 5.6 ] ~= 4.2` since it takes an additional argument `b`. Are you sure you didn't miss something in either of them? If MagicHaskeller indeed reported that function for that spec, I would regard it as a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite, but close.

`f` **is** a function (it's a name bound to a lambda expression) that takes two arguments: a list of numbers `a` and some `b` that is completely ignored. The function returns the sum of the numbers in the list divided by three.

Comment: \a is syntax for some list of type a in Haskell ?

Comment: `\ ` introduces a lambda expression. It is followed by the arguments (`a b` here) and an arrow.

Comment: @blue-sky Usually, the lambda expression is not used directly; `f a b = sum a / 3` might be more familiar to you.

Comment: @blue-sky `\a -> e` is syntax for a function which takes an argument, names it `a`, and returns `e`.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner how is the compiler inferring that 'a' contains the sum function? As 'a' is a generic type.

Comment: @blue-sky The compiler doesn't; MagicHaskeller is a separate program that takes a  specification and tries to deduce valid definitions that fit the specification. Such a function isn't unique; `g a = 4.2` is also a valid function that fits the specification. The "magic" is in trying to determine a function that matches a human's intuition as to which function is intended by a specification.

Comment: @blue-sky `a` does not contain the sum function, and `a` is not a type. So ask more questions: you have misunderstood something farther up your inference chain then the question you are currently asking.

Comment: @DanielWagner 'f = (\a b -> sum a / 3) ' is a lambda abstraction ? as described in section 3.1 of https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/functions.html . a is not typed at compile time but the sum function is applied to the a type. put another way 'sum a' is the same as 'sum(a)' , is this correct ? 'a' has to be of some type otherwise its generic ?

Comment: @blue-sky Yes, `f = \a b -> sum a/3` is a lambda abstraction. No, `a` is typed at compile time (to a first approximation, types do not exist at runtime). No, the `sum` function is applied to the *term* `a` -- `a` is not a type (though it has a type). Yes, `sum a` and `sum(a)` are the same. I don't know what "generic" means, so I can't answer the last question. I still feel like we are talking past each other -- but I can't work out exactly where our difference in understanding is.

Comment: @DanielWagner by generic I mean (coming from a Java background) that the 'a' does not have a type so how can the compiler agree that 'a' is allowed to be used with sum as 'a' is not of type Num. I think this will clear it up for me : what is the difference between 'a' not being a type and 'a' having a type ? thanks for this detail.

Comment: @blue-sky `a` having a type and `a` being a type are completely different things.

Comment: @blue-sky The compiler will verify that `a`'s type is an instance of `Num` before agreeing to apply `sum`. For your second question: "`a` having a type" means that `a` is a term, and it's used in a consistent way in all the places it's used (e.g. isn't used as if it were a `Bool` in one place and as if it were a `Double` in another); on the other hand, `a` *being* a type means that it is a description of a consistent way to use terms. Compare: `3` has type `Int`; `3` is not a type, but `Int` is a type.